# Function returns wrong value for certain arrays

Tags: python, function

I have recently started coding and was working on a function that returns the 3 largest numbers in a given array. The function works for most arrays, but not for others. Below is the code:

```
def findThreeLargestNumbers(array):
  list = []
  if len(set(array)) != 1:
    while len(list) <= 2:
      for element in array:
        if element == max(array):
          list.append(element)
          array.remove(element)
    list.reverse()
    return list
  else:
    for element in array:
      newlist = [element, element, element]
      return newlist
```

For instance, when I input the array [1,2,3,4,5] the function returns [3,4,5]. However, when I input [55, 43, 11, 3, -3, 10], the function returns 4 values: [10, 11, 43, 55].

Why is this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a break in the end of the for

```
  def findThreeLargestNumbers(array):
      list = []
      if len(set(array)) != 1:
        while len(list) <= 2:
          for element in array:
            if element == max(array):
              list.append(element)
              array.remove(element)
              break
        list.reverse()
        return list
      else:
        for element in array:
          newlist = [element, element, element]
          return newlist
```

Comment: Thank you, that works!!! How come the break statement solves this issue?

Comment: Once you've tested that you have less than three items in your "list" list (via the `while` loop), you proceed to add potentially all the items from the "array" list within the for loop, providing that they are sorted decreasingly.

Note that you really should never use `list` as a variable name in python, as doing so occults the `list` type, which will cause all sort of problems down the line.

Comment: Thanks. When the for statement continues, and when you remove the max element, a new max its "created", and the comparation continues, and this will be the problem

Comment: Thanks! I am just confused as to why the while loop doesn't control the length of the list already!

Answer (score 0):

This nested loop can add an arbitrarily large number of elements to `list` (which is btw a bad name for a list because it overwrites the builtin function `list()`):

```
    while len(list) <= 2:
      for element in array:
        if element == max(array):
          list.append(element)
          array.remove(element)
```

You only check the length of `list` in the outer loop, but the inner loop goes over the entire array and will potentially add all of them to `list` (if the array is in reverse-sorted order) before the condition is checked again.

A much simpler way to write this function would be to simply sort it and take the highest three elements:

```
from typing import List

def find_three_largest_numbers(array: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    """Return the three largest numbers from the array."""
    return sorted(array)[-3:]
```

(edit) A slightly more complex version that doesn't involve a sort:

```
def find_three_largest_numbers(array: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    """Return the three largest numbers from the array."""
    largest_3: List[int] = []
    for num in array:
        largest_3.append(num)
        if len(largest_3) > 3:
            largest_3.remove(min(largest_3))
    return largest_3
```

In this implementation, `largest_3` is never permitted to grow beyond 3 elements because every time it grows to 4, we remove exactly one element before we add any more.

Comment: sorting is O(NlogN), "three largest" is O(N) problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would have tried to sort the array, but the prompt specifically asked me not to! I was wondering how come the nested loop sometimes adds the extra value, returning a list with 4 values in some cases, yet sometimes it doesn't and returns a list with 3 values?

Comment: As I said, the nested loop the way you've coded it can add a variable number of values.

Comment: Algorithmic complexity is not always a goal for wich every sacrifice need to be made. If this function will only be used with small lists, I'd rather have the **sort** version in my codebase.